# IE and Safari failing on .set()

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, internet-explorer, safari, antd

I am trying to log users in through this fetch on a Wordpress site but the fetch. I am pulling form data from an Ant Design form.

```
fetch('/wp-login.php?wpe-login=true', {
  method: 'POST',
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  body: [
    ['log', 'form_username'],
    ['pwd', 'form_password'],
    ['wp-submit', 'form_wp-submit'],
    ['redirect_to', 'form_redirect_to'],
  ].reduce(
    (a, [k, field]) => a.set(k, form.getFieldValue(field)) || a,
    new FormData(),
  ),
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

Safari throws the following error:

> TypeError: a.set is not a function. (In 'a.set(k, form.getFieldValue(field))', 'a.set' is undefined)

IE throws this:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set'

I am not sure what the issue is here. There are no duplicate ids and or form fields which is the only thing I could find when I was trying to research about this.

Comment: Check the return value of  `a.set(k, form.getFieldValue(field))`. For the `reduce` to work the return value must be falsy for the `|| a` to kick in. If in those browsers the return value of `a.set(k, form.getFieldValue(field))` is not falsy then put a body to the function and `return a;`

Comment: Remove `mode: 'no-cors'`